# Rejected migrations don't provide close information

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

A post was [migrated to Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/236539). Someone disliked the migration and [posted on Stack Overflow's meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393516). The meta post states a reason that doesn't apply to the post, and so I wanted to see what reason it was closed for.

However when looking at the post it only says:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.

[image: Image of the above quote.]

I have 25k so I don't see why I'm being served the public reason. If it were not a migration it would tell me why it's been closed, and by who.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying you can't see the close reasons on the question on Stack Overflow or the one on Code Review?

Comment: @BrianNickel The one on Code Review. I have attached an image in case there are any other sources of confusion.

Comment: ‍♂️ I misunderstood the problem and spent a good chunk of yesterday documenting a similar behavior on the question on Stack Overflow.  I've replicated this locally and am trying to track the root cause.

Comment: Oh no! I'm so sorry @BrianNickel. Thank you for looking into this

Comment: A change is in review.  The problem was in how we determine if you can see close reasons.  It's supposed to be if you have the close/reopen privilege, but we were checking if you could reopen that specific post.  Since returned questions are locked, you can't reopen the question so we thought you were a low rep user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fixed.

The problem was as I described in the comments: We were checking if you had the close/reopen privilege based on whether or not you could reopen that post.  Since the returned question was locked, you couldn't reopen it, so you couldn't see the close reasons.

The logic has been simplified to only check if the user has the privilege.